# Downloading the Ether Mist Multisig Wallet..blockchain download time..and future syncing

Tags: wallets

Hi i'm intrested in purchasing some ether.. and think the Mist Multisig wallet is a good place to keep it.

So I downloaded the wallet...now the blockchain(syncing) is downloading and has been running for a few hours.

I just wanted to know is this a once off thing, I mainly plan on buyn a few ether/ cyptocoins as a speculative and not really doin much for say a few years...
I don't plan on mining either. So is it goin to sync every time I open this wallet???